# How to get SQLException with message and error code from Ibatis

Tags: java, ibatis

I am new at Ibatis. I trying to catch the SQL exception and error code, but i unable to find it. Ibatis exceptions are runtime exception. So How do I find the SQL error message and error code. The exceptions I catch look like:

> com.common.dao.BaseDaoImpl:167 - Error Code Captured Create Category
>   Master : Failed to insert - id [createMaster], parameterObject
>   [com.mslkp.vo.msklpVO@a27b9e]. Cause:
>   com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>
> --- The error occurred in com/sql/createMSLKP.xml.
>
> --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
>
> --- Check the createMSLKP-InlineParameterMap.
>
> --- Check the statement (update failed).
>
> --- Cause: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MS"."T_MSTR_LKUP"."DELET_FLG")

How do I catch error code like 01400?

Comment: Catch  the `NestedSQLException` (or whatever other wrapping exception it is) and get its `cause`.

Comment: Actualy com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.RuntimeSQLException as well as it's subclasses has a method getErrorCode(), give it a try